# Pigeonhole Principle- a general case for odd number's of positive integers and the product

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, pigeonhole-principle

Let $A={a_1,a_2...,a_{2k+1}}$ where $k\geq 1$ ,be  a set of $2k+1$ positive integers. 
\
show:that : for :any:**premutation**    $a_{i1},a_{i2},a_{i2k+1}$ of A, the product $\prod_{j=1}^{2k+1}(a_i-a_j)$ is allways even:

My solution:
i divide the problem to 2 boxes box1 is even numbers and box2 is odd numbers
second,define the pigeon to be the numbers and the holes to be the boxes
third,denote that ${a_{i1},a_{i2},...a_{i2k+1}}\bigcap {a_1,a_2...a_{2k+1}}\neq\emptyset$ beacuse if it was then we had 2k numbers in 2 boxes and this is not true.
so we suppose $a_t=a_{ik}$ and therfore:$a_3-a_{ik}=a_3-a_t$ ,therefore,the factor $(a_t-a{ik})$ is even , and therefore we proved the existence of product of some 2 numbers is even.

**is it valid?**

Comment: The question isn't clear what is $a_{i1}$ $a_{i2}$ .

Answer (score 1):

I would try to prove by contradiction. Assume there exists some permutation such that the product is odd. In order for the product to be odd, every term of the multiplication must be odd. Terms of the product are all differences of terms of the original sequence. So, we can look at terms of the original sequence to try to determine its parity.

$a_i-a_j$ is even if $a_i$ and $a_j$ are either both odd or both even. The difference is odd if and only if the two have different parity. In order to construct a product that is odd, you must permute the numbers so that every even number is permuted to the position of an odd number in the original sequence and every odd number is permuted to the position of an even number in the original sequence.

Suppose you have $m$ even numbers and $n$ odd numbers such that $m+n=2k+1$. Then, the permutation yielding an odd product requires the $m$ even numbers to be permuted to the positions of the $n$ odd numbers and vise versa. This is only possible if $m=n$, which contradicts the fact that $m+n$ is odd.

Comment: looks valid,but i would say,it is very long,compare to my suggested solution.

Comment: The suggested solution you provided is difficult to follow, and may be false. Look up [Derangements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement). They are specific permutations where no element winds up in its original position. Even if you have an odd number of elements, you need not have any element wind up in its original position. With a derangement, you may not have any element $a_t = a_{ik}$. Now, if you were only discussing the parity (oddness or evenness) of the terms of the sequence, then you may want to be more explicit with what you mean in your solution, and I am still not certain

Comment: ... that I follow your thought process.

Comment: " only discussing the parity (oddness or evenness) of the terms of the sequence", yes, this is the way, see ,i had a solution of a specific problem , and i implied it to the general case, so i wanted to be sure. could you suggest , a solution in the same way that i provided, but with the correct attitude , so it will be clear enough?

Comment: How about define $$\pi:[2k+1] \to [2k+1]$$ to be a bijection (it is an arbitrary permutation of the indexes of the original sequence). Since the product $$\prod_{j=1}^{2k+1}(a_j - a_{\pi(j)}) \equiv 1 \pmod{2} \iff \forall j, a_j -a_{\pi(j)} \equiv 1 \pmod{2}$$, it is odd if and only if $$\left| \{j \in [2k+1]: a_j \equiv 0 \pmod 2\} \right| = \left| \{j \in [2k+1]: a_j \equiv 1 \pmod{2} \} \right|$$ However, this forms a partition on $[2k+1]$, which contains an odd number of elements, and cannot be split evenly into two partitions.

Comment: Oops, my statement that "the product [...] is odd if and only if ..." should have been "the product [...] is odd only if ...". What follows is only a necessary condition, not a sufficient one.